# Filter list view by current year on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, filter

I have a year column in one of the SharePoint list.

I want to create a view to filter the items by current year.

How to do this?

I have tried a lot but it doesnt work.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use calculated columns to achieve that:

1. Have a year column called "Year".
2. Create a calculated column called "startOfYear" with the following formula to get the first day of this "Year":

   `=DATE([Year],1,1)`

   [image]
3. Create a calculated column called "endOfYear" with the following formula the get the last day of this "Year":

   `=DATE([Year],12,31)`

   [image]
4. You will get:

   [image]
5. Create a view and configure the filter to only display items which the "Year" is current year.

   [image]

**Update:**

For displaying items that the year is not equal to current year:

[image]

Comment: Can i use excel formulas like YEAR(TODAY()) in view filter?

Comment: I created a calculated column base on this TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy"), it successfully returned the current year 2019.
But when i used this as a filter condition on my views, it doesnt work.. can you plss explain

Comment: Also i want to filter those items that the year is not equal to current year, how to do that

Comment: No, we cannot use YEAR(TODAY()). We cannot filter items when Column is equal to another column, for example column "Year" is equal to the calculated column (=TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy")), it does not support. It only supports [Today] or [Me] as the column value. For displaying items that the year is not equal to current year, check the update.

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: @JoannaW_MSFT I know this is an old post, but what you can do here (for you and anyone finding it), is in the Calculated column "End of Year" you can do `=DATE(TEXT(Created,"yyyy"),12,31)` and then you can filter the view to say something like "Due Date is less than or equal to End of Year". Then it would show anything due that year, as long as the Due Date was assigned appropriately. So I think Dan's problem is he's trying to put the formula directly into the view's filter, and it won't let you do that. Also, you couldn't use a Text Year to compare against, instead of an entire date, anyway.

Comment: @JoannaW_MSFT Great answer, here, btw. Helped me create a nice view for upcoming publication dates for the year, which they'll be expanding on with new dates in the coming years, so we had to restrict what we showed to just this year's dates when someone wanted to know when they had to submit by, and we have a workflow that will email them the next date, which I was able to provide this view to assist with. Simply ordered by the date, desc, and did a "Assign to each", and within it, saved the value to a variable. So the last value in the variable is the right one. :)